# Grid slider with custom post type (how to filter with taxonomies?)

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, slideshow

I managed to use [Radiant Scroller](https://www.jqueryscript.net/slider/Responsive-jQuery-Layout-Carousel-Slider-Plugin-RadiantScroller.html) to create a slider grid of posts for my custom post type (zee_work). It serves as a display of portfolio items in a very clean neat way, but I need to filter the posts in order to show all the posts (default) and any other category (that number could change if I add more categories).

The code I have is this:

```
<?php 

$works = get_posts( 
array(
'post_type'=>'zee_work', 
'orderby' => 'date',
'order' => 'DESC',
'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
?>

<div id="portfolio" class="clearfix">
```

This is the grid slider (working smooth):

```
<div id="myScroller">
<?php foreach ($works as $key => $work) {
 ?>
<div class="scroller-el">
<a href="<?php the_permalink($work->ID)?>">
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $work->ID, 'work-thumb', array( 
      'class' => "img-responsive", 
      'alt' => trim(strip_tags( $work->post_title )),
      'title' => trim(strip_tags( $work->post_title ))
      ));     ?>      </a>
       </div>
   <?php } ?>
   </div>
   </div>
```

How do I do a foreach of every category (custom tax) on my zee_work posts to filter the slider? I need help! :c

**UPDATE**

I managed to add a filter on top using isotope and the filtering works *BUT* the default view (all) 'hardcodes' the pagination so if for example, the first time the page loads with all the items the slider has 3 pages, the filtering that occurs next will keep 3 pages even if items fit in only one, and the items are distributed in all 3 pages so it leaves empty spaces in the grid.... oh boy...

```
<ul class="portfolio-filter">
<li><a class="btn btn-default active" href="#" data-filter="*">
<?php _e('All', ZEETEXTDOMAIN); ?></a></li>
<?php 
$terms = get_terms('cat_work', array('hide_empty'=> true));
foreach ($terms as $term) {
?>
<li><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-filter=".<?php echo $term->slug ?>"><?php echo $term->name ?></a></li>
<?php
}
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you need to display it based on categories?

Comment: Yes, I need buttons top (like a filter) that either load a different slideshow with the posts from a different category or change the items in this slider to that posts. I tried using isotope but the grid that loads from the first items wont change item counts when new items are loaded so it messes up the layout